# Layout view shaded with blue and red tint

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I was working on my model, and decided to switch to cycles. Everything was working fine and then suddenly the viewport started giving everything a blue and red tint to it. Depending on whether I recalculate the inside or outside normals. The model renders fine, but for some reason the Layout tab shows this weird tint which makes it hard to see what is being done to the model.

[Here is the HDR image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XMVzcOVKQLF272cLtGULNTFP4IgeuPG1/view?usp=sharing)

Here is my model

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You likely have **Face Orientation** turned on:

[image: Faces]

Comment: That was it. What's face orientation used for? I've only been using blender for a month or so now, so I turn knobs on accident here and there and then have to spend a day or two figuring out what I did wrong.

Comment: Face orientation is primarily used for exactly what you accidentally discovered - it allows you to easily see what direction faces are pointing, defined by normal direction.